# Which flags for Activities to use if changing orientation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, orientation

I'm writing Login/Register system and have the following situation:

1. In `onResume()` from "Home" Activity I call Login Activity which theme
   is Dialog.
2. In Login I have Register button and when I click it I go to Register
   Activity which theme is also Dialog.
3. When I change the orientation Android calls `onResume()` from "Home"
   Activity and shows the Login on the top of Register.

(**More info:** I don't want to loose the possibility to change the orientation; Login page have to be shown everytime when I press Home or Lock button and return to the app, but this isn't so important here)

**So, this is my question:**
I need to use `addFlags()` when I call Login and Register, but which one in order my activities to stay in stack in this order: *Home - Login - Register*, but not: *Home - Login - Register - **Login***? (The second Login is created when we change orientation and Android calls automatically  `onResume()`).

Here is a part of my code:

From Home:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginDialog.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY );// which flags?
        startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

From Login:

```
    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginDialog.this, RegisterDialog.class);
            // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_??? ); // which flags?
            startActivityForResult(intent, REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So your register dialog survives the rotation without being re-launched from onResume() - I would think that means the login activity doesn't need to be launched again either?  Perhaps the solution doesn't lie in changing flags, but in logic to stop startActivityForResult() from being called the 2nd time?

Comment: Eric, you have right, I don't need the function `addFlags()`. I'll use a boolean variable in `onResume()` to check if the Login dialog is already in use.  `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` will save and restore its value when orientation is changing.